# Is this question on-topic for Electronics?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A user posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38612478/656243) on Stack Overflow. I close-voted and left a comment that it felt like an electronics question. They then [posted the question to SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1105842/105558).

I asked them why they didn't post it on Electronics, which was met with:

> The questions I´ve looked at have nothing to do with my question, or
>   does not answer it in a manner I understand (ie software developer
>   perspective).

Before I push for them to post to Electronics another time, I thought I'd verify that the question is on-topic and answerable. Should I continue recommending that the OP posts it here?

(Edit: if you think that it IS a software question, please let me know that too, and I'll be happy join in a re-open vote.)

Comment: SuperUser is a better venue for this question, I think.

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's really not a EE.SE question, and there's a two main reasons for it:

- It's a high-level question about computer software (video drivers).
- It is not an electronics design question

In *general*, one should be familiar with the standards and requirements of a site they recommend migration to - just because it's off-topic on one site doesn't make it on-topic or a good question somewhere else.

Comment: And vis-versa, just because it's on-topic on another site doesn't make it off-topic on the first one.